# Redux rejects my form and data when submitted from within a modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, redux-toolkit, daisyui

I have a modal created with Tailwind/DaisyUI in my React project. We are using Redux Toolkit for state management. I am trying to use this modal to display a form that allows the user to update tickets. I actually copied most of the form from my CreateTicket.jsx page. When I click the submit button, Redux does updateTicket>Pending and then goes to updateTicket>Rejected and I cannot get it to go to updateTicket>Fulfilled. I'm not even sure what to investigate at this point because there doesn't seem to be any error in the backend or frontend console, or anything like that.

I have confirmed that the updateTicket functionality in the TicketService.js works fine (this is where you actually hit the API endpoint from). Beyond that, I recently reintroduced the 'isLoading' piece of state into the TicketSlice.js and then added explicit cases for pending and rejected - before that there was no isLoading state and the only declared case was updateTicket.fulfille. Unfortunately, this didn't change anything. For now, I'm leaving it there - but will likely remove it if it really isn't necessary.

Relevant code from the Ticket.jsx page where the modal is

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import BackButton from '../components/BackButton';
import {
  getTicket,
  closeTicket,
  updateTicket,
} from '../features/tickets/ticketSlice';
import { useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Spinner from '../components/Spinner';

function Ticket() {
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const { ticket, isLoading } = useSelector((state) => state.tickets);

  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState(user.firstName);
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState(user.lastName);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState(user.email);
  const [subject, setSubject] = useState('');
  const [priority, setPriority] = useState('low');
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('');

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { ticketId } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getTicket(ticketId)).unwrap().catch(toast.error);
  }, [dispatch, ticketId]);

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(updateTicket({ subject, priority, description }))
      .unwrap()
      .then(() => {
        navigate('/tickets');
        toast.success('Ticket updated successfully');
      })
      .catch(toast.error);
  };

  if (!ticket || isLoading) {
    return <Spinner />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <BackButton />
      <label htmlFor='edit-ticket-modal' className='btn btn-outline'>
        Open Modal
      </label>
      <input type='checkbox' id='edit-ticket-modal' className='modal-toggle' />
      <label htmlFor='edit-ticket-modal' className='modal cursor-pointer'>
        <label className='modal-box relative' htmlFor=''>
          <label className='label'>
            <span className='font-bold text-xl label-text'>
              Customer First Name
            </span>
          </label>
          <input
            type='text'
            className='input input-md w-full'
            value={firstName}
            disabled
          />
          <label className='label'>
            <span className='font-bold text-xl label-text'>
              Customer Last Name
            </span>
          </label>
          <input
            type='text'
            className='input input-bordered input-md w-full'
            value={lastName}
            disabled
          />
          <label className='label'>
            <span className='font-bold text-xl label-text'>Customer Email</span>
          </label>
          <input
            type='text'
            className='input input-bordered input-md w-full'
            value={email}
            disabled
          />
          <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className='flex flex-col'>
            <label className='label'>
              <span className='font-bold text-xl label-text'>Subject</span>
            </label>
            <input
              type='text'
              className='input input-bordered input-md w-full'
              value={subject}
              placeholder='Subject'
              onChange={(e) => setSubject(e.target.value)}
            />
            <label className='label'>
              <span className='font-bold text-xl label-text'>Priority</span>
            </label>
            <select
              name='priority'
              className='select select-bordered w-full'
              value={priority}
              onChange={(e) => setPriority(e.target.value)}
            >
              <option value='low'>Low</option>
              <option value='medium'>Medium</option>
              <option value='high'>High</option>
            </select>
            <label className='label'>
              <span className='font-bold text-xl label-text'>Description</span>
            </label>
            <textarea
              name='description'
              placeholder='Description'
              className='textarea textarea-bordered h-24'
              value={description}
              onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
            />
            <div>
              <button className='btn btn-outline w-48 mt-5'>Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </label>
      </label>
    </>
  );
}

export default Ticket;
```

Relevant code from TicketSlice.js (Edited to add console.error(error))

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { extractErrorMessage } from '../../utils';
import ticketService from './ticketService';

const initialState = {
  tickets: [],
  ticket: {},
  isLoading: false,
};

// Update user ticket
export const updateTicket = createAsyncThunk(
  'tickets/updateTicket',
  async (ticketId, ticketData, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return await ticketService.updateTicket(ticketId, ticketData, token);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(extractErrorMessage(error));
    }
  }
);

export const ticketSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'ticket',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(getTickets.pending, (state) => {
        state.ticket = null;
      })
      .addCase(getTickets.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.tickets = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(getTicket.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.ticket = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(closeTicket.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.ticket = action.payload;
        state.tickets = state.tickets.map((ticket) => {
          // NOTE: we could remove the 'return' and the curly braces
          // that wrap the return statement or we can do it this way
          return ticket._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : ticket;
        });
      })
      .addCase(updateTicket.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(updateTicket.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
      })
      .addCase(updateTicket.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.ticket = action.payload;
        state.tickets = state.tickets.map((ticket) => {
          // NOTE: we could remove the 'return' and the curly braces  that wrap the return statement or we can do it this way
          return ticket._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : ticket;
        });
      });
  },
});
```

After some more troubleshooting and w/ the suggestions from a reply here, I've got some error info to add:

This is the error within the payload of tickets/updateTicket/rejected:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rejectWithValue') at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2648:21 at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6427:86 at step (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:5122:17) at Object.next (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:5071:14) at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:5184:61 at new Promise (<anonymous>) at __async (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:5166:10) at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6389:18 at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6465:10 at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:77375:18"
```

Doesn't seem entirely useful, but I also got an error by adding console.error(error) into my trycatch which is similarly hard to understand:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getState')
    at ticketSlice.js:55:1
    at createAsyncThunk.ts:634:1
    at step (RefreshUtils.js:271:1)
    at Object.next (RefreshUtils.js:271:1)
    at RefreshUtils.js:271:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __async (RefreshUtils.js:271:1)
    at createAsyncThunk.ts:599:1
    at createAsyncThunk.ts:684:1
    at index.js:16:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I had added an extra parameter into the arrow function parameter of the 'createAsyncThunk' thinking that was how one would get and use both the ticketId and ticketData. The fix was to only pass the ticketData, and then extract the ticketId from the ticketData because that arrow function only takes 2 parameters in total per the documentation and those parameters are 'arg' and thunkAPI. You cannot have three. The new code that works is:

```
// Update user ticket
export const updateTicket = createAsyncThunk(
  'tickets/updateTicket',
  async (ticketData, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return await ticketService.updateTicket(ticketData, token);
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(extractErrorMessage(error));
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Redux does updateTicket>Pending and then goes to updateTicket>Rejected and I cannot get it to go to updateTicket>Fulfilled

This means that your code is entering the `catch` block of your `createAsyncThunk`.  It could be either a API error or an error in your JavaScript code, for example if `state.auth.user` is not an object then you will get a fatal error when you try to access `.token`.

> I'm not even sure what to investigate at this point because there doesn't seem to be any error in the backend or frontend console, or anything like that.

The error is not getting logged because you caught it in your `catch` block.  But it's somewhere in here:

```
// Update user ticket
export const updateTicket = createAsyncThunk(
  'tickets/updateTicket',
  async (ticketId, ticketData, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return await ticketService.updateTicket(ticketId, ticketData, token);
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(extractErrorMessage(error));
    }
  }
);
```

**You need to figure out what the error is**.

Here are some debugging suggestions:

- Check the Redux Dev Tools to see what the `payload` is on your `tickets/updateTicket/rejected` action.  This will be the value of `extractErrorMessage(error)` from your `rejectWithValue`.
- Add a `console.error(error)` before the `return` in your `catch` block. (For debugging only.  You'll probably want to remove this later.)
- Remove the `try`/`catch` block and let `createAsyncThunk` catch the error on its own.  This way you'll get [the whole error object](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-errors) in the `error` property of your rejected action. (But you'd need to rethink your toasts)
- Examine the value of your unwrapped error before calling `toast.error`.  I have a theory that there could be a JavaScript runtime error in your `extractErrorMessage(error)` function.  Otherwise I cannot explain why your `.unwrap().catch(toast.error);` is not working as it looks like you've written it correctly.  You've `rejectedWithValue` with a `string` therefore your unwrapped error should be a `string`.  An uncaught error inside the `catch` block would cause the value here to be an error object instead.  So you can add in some temporary logging here to check what you have: `catch((e) => { console.error(e); toast.error(e); })`

Comment: Thanks for the response - I had already added the console.error(error) awhile after I posted this question and it gave me an error I could hardly track down to anything useful. I also (using your suggestions) was able to find the error that was in the payload of tickets/updateTicket/rejected. I'm adding both of these errors to the bottom of my initial post. Still can't figure what to do with them after awhile of looking for others with similar issues.